# "Per-document consistent" in App Engine Search

Tags: google-app-engine

Just reading through the search api documentation and have come across a stack overflow question with an answer that mentions a default "per-document consistent" indexes ([Appengine Search API - Globally Consistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313118/appengine-search-api-globally-consistent)).

I can't find any mention of this term in the App Engine documentation for the Search API and was wondering what this meant (or point me in the right direction).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Globally consistent indexes were deprecated in Version 1.7.3 (See: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes#Version_1.7.3_-_October_23,_2012)

The difference between consistency modes is explained in the source here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/search/search.py?r=281#2334

Specifically:

> Consistency modes supported by indexes. When creating an index you
>     may request whether the index is GLOBALLY_CONSISTENT or
>     PER_DOCUMENT_CONSISTENT. An index with GLOBALLY_CONSISTENT mode set, when
>     searched, returns results with all changes prior to the search request,
>     committted. For an index with PER_DOCUMENT_CONSISTENT mode set, a search
>     result may contain some out of date documents. However, any two changes
>     to any document stored in such an index are applied in the correct order.
>     The benefit of PER_DOCUMENT_CONSISTENT is that it provides much higher
>     index document throughput than a globally consistent one.
>
> Typically, you would use GLOBALLY_CONSISTENT if organizing personal
>   user   information, to reflect all changes known to the user in any
>   search results.   PER_DOCUMENT_CONSISTENT should be used in indexes
>   that amalgamate   information from multiple sources, where no single
>   user is aware of all   collected data.